# Nesting quotes in bash

Tags: bash, escaping

I want to something like this in bash:

```
 alias foo='bar="$(echo hello world | grep \"hello world\")"; echo $bar;'; foo
```

Expected output: hello world

Ouput: grep: world": No such file or directory

- The outer quotes have to be single quotes, with double quotes $bar would be empty.
- The next quotes have to be double quotes, with single quotes $() wouldn't expand.
- The inner quotes could be both type of quotes, but single quotes doesn't allow single quotes inside of them.

How to I achieve this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The stuff inside `$()` represents a subshell, so you are allowed to place un-escaped double quotes inside

```
alias foo='bar="$(echo testing hello world | grep "hello world")"; echo "$bar"'
```

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit unclear what "something like this" means, but the simplest way to achieve what seems to be the point here is a simple function:

```
foo() {
    echo 'hello world' | grep 'hello world'
}
foo
```

- There's no need for an intermediate variable assignment (it will be lost anyway).
- Functions are generally preferred over aliases because of more flexibility (parameter handling) and readability (multiple lines; less escaping).
- Always use **the simplest solution which could possibly work**.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the spaces

```
alias foo='bar="$(echo hello world | grep hello\ world)"; echo $bar;'
```

Comment: Is it not possible to escape quotes, say i wan to do: `alias foo='baz="hello world"; bar="$(echo hello world | grep \"$baz\")"; echo $bar;'; foo`

Answer (score 0):

The double quotes around `$()` are not necessary:

```
alias foo='bar=$(echo hello world | grep "hello world"); echo $bar;'
foo

# Output:
hello world
```